scikit-image fails to install under Fedora 41
It looks like there's an issue with Python here. Other times I've found this to be an issue online it's related to incorrect versions of Python. But this line:
      Program python found: YES (/home/almo/Almo/AIStuff/StableDiffusion/stable-diffusion-webui-forge/venv/bin/python)

seems to indicate it's found that fine, and it's happy with the version.
I'm not sure if it matters, but this is while trying to install and run the stable-diffusion-webui-forge package. I've installed Python 3.12 as this package wants that version. The output of the Meson build process follows.
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]
      + meson setup /tmp/pip-install-bid8k5j6/scikit-image_d4c704ffff0b4dceb33eb5847bd24583 /tmp/pip-install-bid8k5j6/scikit-image_d4c704ffff0b4dceb33eb5847bd24583/.mesonpy-imb1wlte -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=/tmp/pip-install-bid8k5j6/scikit-image_d4c704ffff0b4dceb33eb5847bd24583/.mesonpy-imb1wlte/meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.6.0
      Source dir: /tmp/pip-install-bid8k5j6/scikit-image_d4c704ffff0b4dceb33eb5847bd24583
      Build dir: /tmp/pip-install-bid8k5j6/scikit-image_d4c704ffff0b4dceb33eb5847bd24583/.mesonpy-imb1wlte
      Build type: native build
      Project name: scikit-image
      Project version: 0.21.0
      C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 14.2.1 "cc (GCC) 14.2.1 20240912 (Red Hat 14.2.1-3)")
      C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.43.1-2
      C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (gcc 14.2.1 "c++ (GCC) 14.2.1 20240912 (Red Hat 14.2.1-3)")
      C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.43.1-2
      Host machine cpu family: x86_64
      Host machine cpu: x86_64
      Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: YES
      Library m found: YES
      Checking if "-Wl,--version-script" : links: YES
      Program cython found: YES (/tmp/pip-build-env-jsqyswj7/overlay/bin/cython)
      Program pythran found: YES (/tmp/pip-build-env-jsqyswj7/overlay/bin/pythran)
      Program cp found: YES (/usr/bin/cp)
      Program python found: YES (/home/almo/Almo/AIStuff/StableDiffusion/stable-diffusion-webui-forge/venv/bin/python)
      Found pkg-config: YES (/usr/bin/pkg-config) 2.3.0
      Run-time dependency python found: NO (tried pkgconfig, pkgconfig and sysconfig)
      
      ../meson.build:69:14: ERROR: Python dependency not found


Meson is trying to build a dependency, and needs the proper headers.
Installing the python3.12-devel package fixed this problem.
